# How to update router from within component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying to update the router from within a component the router posts to. Here is the main page with a navbar and Routes to the various pages.

```
class Page extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Navbar id="navbar" variant="dark">
          <Navbar.Toggle />
          <Navbar.Collapse className="justify-content-end">
            <Navbar.Text>
              <Link to="/member">Login</Link>
            </Navbar.Text>
          </Navbar.Collapse>
        </Navbar>
        <Route path="/" exact component={LandingPage} />
        <Route path="/member" component={MemberPage} />
        <Route path="/apply" component={Apply} />
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

When I load the LandingPage component, I have this right now:

```
class LandingPage extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Router>
              <div className="apply">
                <Link to="/apply">Apply Now</Link>
              </div>
            </Router>
        );
    }
}
```

So when I click the link, it changes the URL to whatever.com/apply but the actual page is not updated. I understand that it is because it is looking for a route inside of this to update, however, how do I get the page to load the next component?

Answer (score 0):

The fix was simple, I just had to remove the router tags from the LandingPage componenet